# Domain and iP change

Tags: dns

One of my client has a special request , here is my problem.
My client have a server in a country with a domainname.com , but he wants the customers see another IP from an other country.

Basically the server can't be on the main country because there is no serious hosting company (little island) . So the server is in the USA. 
But if someone do a domain to ip , the IP must be an IP of the little island.

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: So, in my understanding, are you asking if you can have an IP address that both *is* and *isn't* on the island at the same time?

Comment: Let's see: a small island, need for IP masquerading... Is this for an internet gambling, or for a porn site? :):):)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight torrent site maybe? I like porn better though :D

Answer (score 0):

There are only two options I think you have:

1. Let them host their website themself (on that little island), setting up a linux server isn't so hard.
2. [Reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)

Basically with the seconds option. You would have a server to which peole make requests for the website. But this server (with local ip) isn't really the webserver, but it only requests data from the webserver. People will not know that this is happening in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can host in outside the island and have a proxy (a server that only redirects the requests) on the island that the DNSes point to.